# PHP delivery time script

Tags: php, html

I am making a delivery time script in PHP. For two dishes, the delivery time should be 30 minutes, and for more dishes, they add up 10 minutes each.

Heres what I've done so far:

```
for ($i=30;$i>;$i=$i+10;) {
    echo "You have ordered " .$number. " dishes, and the delivery time is " .$time;
}
```

I cant figure out how I should proceed. Could someone please help me out? It would be great if it could be in the for-loop form.

Thanks!

Comment: you have syntax error in your for loop!!!

Comment: Just encapsulated the coding tags , nothing else.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran there should have been a warning upon submission that the question had been edited, but no problem: fixed.

Comment: Right now, you don’t even have a valid syntax, the condition for your for loop is wrong. And this has little to do with a loop at all, it’s a simple math operation instead – for 2 or less dishes, the time is 30 min, and for anything above it’s `30 + (dishes - 2) * 10` minutes. (If _“they add up 10 minutes each”_ was supposed to mean that, it’s a little ambiguous.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
$delivery = 30; //30 minutes by default

if($numDishes > 2){
    $extra = $numDishes - 2;
    $delivery = $delivery + ($extra * 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I would prefer if I could do it with a for-loop. You have given me inspiration though, thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that with a for loop

Comment: @user3040915 A FOR loop would be kind of overkill for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Really, thats basics...

```
$time = 30; // initial, could not be lower.
for($i=1;$i<$numDishes;$i++){
   // after the first one, add 10 to each other
   $time += 10;
}
```

edit.. oh I just saw you have 2 for 30mins, then the easiest way is the answer by Wayne

Comment: Thanks! I am a real PHP-newbie, so I guess it is. :)